# Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain

Tags: apache, centos7

My httpd.conf file ( vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/example.com.conf )

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/snipe-it/public
    <Directory /var/www/snipe-it/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file ( /etc/hosts) :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 example.com
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6 example.com
```

when i run apachectl configtest
it gives me

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
>   qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the
>   'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

I am trying to test locally if example.com can be display in the browser but it couldn't ( page cannot be found ) , does the above error affect it ? How do i solved the error , where did i go wrong? i know that it must be a FQDN but it must be an actual domain or we can make one up just for testing?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the `httpd.conf`, add bellow line, or change that line to this:

```
ServerName localhost:80
```